# I have a question about the error that occurs when I add a Generic-based class to a Component as a Singleton in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics

- situation

I want to implement a generic-based 'PoolingManagerBase' in a singleton pattern for class pooling.

- Question

Why is it that a class that inherits from 'PoolingManagerBase' does not create a component that contains a singleton instance?

- Configuration

First, I implement the generic-based 'Singleton' class.

The 'Singleton' class code looks like this

```cs
public abstract class Singleton<T> : CComponent where T : CComponent
{
    private static T _Instance = null;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Instance == null)
            {
                GameObject gObject = new GameObject(typeof(T).ToString());
                _Instance = gObject.AddComponent<T>();

                DontDestroyOnLoad(gObject);
            }
            return _Instance;
        }
    }

    public static T Create() => Instance;
}
```

Items are also held in the form of 'PoolingItemBase' and scoped to ITEM as below

```
public class PoolingItemBase where ITEM : PoolingItemBase<ITEM>
```

Therefore, the item manager also scopes ITEM as below

```
public class PoolingManagerBase <ITEM>: Singleton <PoolingManagerBase<ITEM>> where ITEM : PoolingItemBase<ITEM>
```

- apply

To actually use it, we construct the child class as shown below.

```
public class TempItem : PoolingItemBase<TempItem>

public class TempItemManager : PoolingManagerBase<TempItem>
```

- result

Singleton's

```
_Instance = gObject.AddComponent<T>();
```

Null is returned in part

I've been shoveling for two days, but I do not have a pointy reason ...

Is there a limit to writing nested generics in Unity?

--------------- EDIT ---------------

1. To distinguish it from the existing Unity Component, I replaced the Singleton inherited Component with CComponent
2. Below is the code for the CComponent class

```
public abstract class CComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public Transform _Transform = null;
    [HideInInspector] public Rigidbody _Rigidbody = null;
    [HideInInspector] public Rigidbody2D _Rigidbody2D = null;

    public virtual void Awake()
    {
        _Transform = transform;
        _Rigidbody = GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody>();
        _Rigidbody2D = GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public virtual void Update()        { }
    public virtual void FixedUpdate()   { }
    public virtual void LateUpdate()    { }
}
```

3. It seems to have come to an answer after thinking about the painful time.
   When I added `_Instance` via `AddComponent<T>()` inside `Singleton`, the type I actually imported came with information about `<T>`, not the lowest class.
   We just learned that Unity does not support generic-based components, so the above code did not work.
   So I modified the `Singleton` with the following code.

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> : CComponent where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static T _Instance = null;
    private static Type _InstanceType = null;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Instance == null)
            {
                GameObject gObject = new GameObject(typeof(T).ToString());
                _Instance = gObject.AddComponent(_InstanceType) as T;

                DontDestroyOnLoad(gObject);
            }
            return _Instance;
        }
    }

    public static T Create(Type tType)
    {
        _InstanceType = tType;
        return Instance;
    }
}
```

I had the inconvenience of going through `Create(typeof(T))`, but now it's working well.

Comment: Sorry... I am Korean and I use translator so I can use poor English

Comment: Any errors occurs while following that procedure?

Comment: Only scripts the derive from `MonoBevahiour` can be added as components to a GameObject. Does your Class `Singleton` inherit from `MonoBehaviour` anywhere?

Comment: Morasiu - Yes, a null is returned when creating an `_instance` through `AddComponant<T>()` in a `singleton`

Comment: remy_rm - `Component` class inherited by `Singleton` inherits `MonoBehaviour`

Comment: Instead of making `new GameObject`, try using [GameObject.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). Maybe this will help

Comment: Morasiu - First, thank you for your continuous reply. I do not have a source to instantiate from something.(because it is Singleton)
Unfortunately, using the `new GameObject` seems to be necessary. Also, the place where the error occurs is the `AddComponent <T>()` part that returns the `_Instance`, so the problem still exists

Comment: @Undouble I;m not quite sure how this code would work your version of `CComponent` does not appear to inherit from `MonoBehavior` or `Component` the `AddComponent` functionality expects a class that inherits from `Component`.  In your use case I do not see a class that inherits from Unity's `Component`.  Can you show us your definition of `CComponent`?

Comment: Of course, `CComponent` is a device that caches `Transform`, `Rigidbody`, and `Rigidbody2D` on `Awake()`

Comment: @Undouble then the only issue I see is `public class PoolingItemBase where ITEM : PoolingItemBase<ITEM>` doesn't inherit from `CComponent`.  I believe you would just want this to be `public class PoolingItemBase : CComponent` and your `public class PoolingManagerBase <ITEM>: Singleton <PoolingManagerBase<ITEM>> where ITEM : PoolingItemBase<ITEM>` should be `public class PoolingManagerBase <ITEM>: Singleton <ITEM> where ITEM : PoolingItemBase`

Comment: @Undouble if `CPoolingItemBase` doesn't inherit from `CComponent` then it doesn't meet the guidelines needed for your singleton, where you say `where T : CComponent`.  at this point it would be best if you could provide a MCVE.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Eddge Thank you for your kind reply.
Unfortunately, when you inherit `CComponent` from`CPoolingItemBase`, the result still returns `Null` in `_Instance`.
First, `CPoolingManagerBase` is made up of `Singleton` generics inherited from `CComponent`, so `_Instance` has children of `CComponent`.
Therefore, I do not think the existence of `CComponent` inheritance of `CPoolingItemBase` has any effect.
Also, the object I want to access with `Singleton` is `PoolingManagerBase`.
`Singleton <PoolingItemBase>`, I think it will not work as intended...

Comment: @Undouble unfortunately I cannot help any further without an MCVE, having an MCVE will allow me to get an accurate idea of what you are trying to do(And the arrangements of your objects), and will allow me to provide more insight specific to the problem you are running into.

Comment: @Eddge Thank you again for your reply.
Your answer gave me a powerful driving force.
Have a nice day. :D